# Настройка OAuth2 через Яндекс ID, используя SpringSecurity

Tags: vue.js, rest, spring-security, cors, oauth2

пытаюсь разобраться с OAuth2. Настроил сервер для авторизации через Yandex ID. Все работает, когда обращасюсь к адресу авторизации сервера через браузер. Но у меня rest api приложение и когда я на клиенте (vue js) пытаюсь обратится к этому же методу, то появляется ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

В заголовке действительно нет поля 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', но тем не менее у клиента есть доступ к другим методам контроллера и никакой ошибки не возникает, хотя там в заголовках также нет этого поля

Мой код SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests)-> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/login-from-yandex").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .oauth2Login();


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(personDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

Конфигурация Cors:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8081")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true); // Разрешение передачи cookies и авторизационных заголовков
        System.out.println("FROM CORS CONFIGURATION");
    }
}
```

Тестовый метод контроллера:

```
@GetMapping("/login-from-yandex")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(principal);
    }
```

Vue js метод:

```
yandexAuthorizated(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/login-from-yandex')
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.yandex = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
    },
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, потому-что я не совсем понимаю, что делать